# One more record and the chart disappears - is there a limit in VL?

Tags: vega, vega-lite, altair

There are 1731 records in my spec. If I add one more record, and give it a unique ID (e.g., 1732), the chart disappears.

I cannot share the URL to the chart because of the body limit. I cannot shorten the URL because it is too long. So, I have to show screenshots.

#### 1731 records:

[image]

#### 1732 records

[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: What happens if you add `#1732` at the end of the dataset, after 1731, instead of before the record with `'person_id': 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas implementation on the web has limited maximum width/height.  Try switching to the SVG renderer.

Comment: Thanks kanitw, how do I make that switch?

Comment: See https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view and https://github.com/vega/vega-embed, depending how you render Vega.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. Thank you so much. Using the Vega Embed API worked perfectly. The entire chart now shows up. I added the option `var embed_opt = {{"mode": "vega-lite", "renderer": "svg"}};`